# i want to show all images in homepage , when i click in home button it automatically goes to another page

Tags: reactjs

```
const Home = () => {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      navigate(`/inventory`);
      return (
        <div>
          <Banner></Banner>
          <InventoryItems></InventoryItems>
          <SafetyGear></SafetyGear>
          <Other></Other>
          <Link to={`/inventory`}>
            {" "}
            <button className="manage-btn">
              <p>Manage Inventories</p>
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `navigate("/inventory");` in the function body of your code. That is why your code goes to another page on load. To fix this, simply remove that line.